# Problem with Tomcat Servlet startup using @WebServlet annotations

Tags: java, servlets, startup, tomcat9

Good morning.

I have a problem with my servlet startup. Could you please help me?
I am using

- Tomcat 9.0.82
- Coretto 11.0.17.8.1
- Windows 10 19045.3570

I have a compiled WAR archive with the following directory structure.

```
   WAR
     - index.htm
     - img
       - some_images.gif
     - WEB-INF
       - web.xml
     - lib/my.jar
       - servlet.HelpServlet.class`
```

The web.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?\>

<!-- Metadata-complete Attribute: If your web.xml contains the attribute 
  metadata-complete="true" in the  tag, this will instruct the server 
  to ignore annotations and use only the web.xml for deployment configuration. -->

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1" metadata-complete="false"\>

  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>wsdl</extension>
    <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>xsd</extension>
    <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
```

The servlet has the following definition:

```
@WebServlet(
name = "HelpServlet",
urlPatterns = "/help/\*")
public class HelpServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2877995723829943551L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        System.out.println("HELP PLEASE");
    }

}
```

My tomcat has the following configuration (Changed from vanilla):

- conf/server.xml
  Changed Port from 8080 to 6080
  `<Host name="localhost"  appBase="../webapp/app" unpackWARs="true"\>`
- conf/Catalina/localhost/app.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
  <Context docBase="D:/app-deploy/webapp/app.war" reloadable="false" />
```

Is there any configuration I have forgotten to configurate that the servlet starts at server startup? The war archive will be deployed in the expected directory. The index.htm could be found and view in the browser, but the HELP-Servlet under localhost:8080/app/help is not found 404!

That's the complete logfile:

```
[09:34:41] <Guest28> 14-Nov-2023 09:29:50.270 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initialisiere ProtocolHandler["http-nio-6080"]
[09:34:41] <Guest28> 14-Nov-2023 09:29:50.319 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1059] milliseconds
[09:34:41] <Guest28> 14-Nov-2023 09:29:50.446 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
[09:34:41] <Guest28> 14-Nov-2023 09:29:50.447 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.82]
[09:34:41] <Guest28> 14-Nov-2023 09:29:50.468 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [D:\java-ide\workspace\webframe-deploy\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\conf\Catalina\localhost\webframe.xml]
[09:34:41] <Guest28> 14-Nov-2023 09:30:30.455 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[09:34:41] <Guest28> 14-Nov-2023 09:33:54.540 WARNUNG [main] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [260] milliseconds.
[09:34:41] <Guest28> 14-Nov-2023 09:33:54.635 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [D:\java-ide\workspace\webframe-deploy\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\conf\Catalina\localhost\webframe.xml] has finished in [244.166] ms
[09:34:41] <Guest28> 14-Nov-2023 09:33:54.638 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-6080"]
[09:34:41] <Guest28> 14-Nov-2023 09:33:54.920 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [244596] milliseconds
```

Expected is that Tomcat starts the defined servlet under [GET] http://localhost:6080/app/help
But currently it is not so.

What's wrong? Please help.
Thanks in advance.
Christian

Comment: Typically, the log file  shows that the web app WAR is deployed on the Tomcat. How have you deployed the web app WAR file on the Tomcat?

Comment: @prasad_ I deployed the web app WAR file with autodeploy at server startup. But I think I have found the problem.

Comment: Also, the `- lib/my.jar`needs to be under the `WEB-INF` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem  I was searching for:

14-Nov-2023 10:56:08.673 SCHWERWIEGEND [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [HelpServlet] in web application [/app] threw load() exception
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: servlet/HelpServlet has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 60.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0 (unable to load class [servlets.HelpServlet])
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2484)

NOTICE!
Don't compile in Eclipse with ANT using buildIn JRE 16 and deploy at Tomcat using JRE 11.